# parse SOAP xml to php

Tags: php, xml, soap

How can I parse a XML response to PHP? I have tried several solutions but nothing works. Here is the XML I get back:

```
<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:body>
    <ns:getrateresponse xmlns:ns="http://services.gts">
        <ns:return xmlns:ax25="http://services.gts/xsd" xmlns:ax26="http://model.gts/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax25:RaterResponseAutoQuotes">

          <ax25:carriers xsi:type="ax25:RaterResponseCarriersAutoQuotes">
                <ax25:accessorials xsi:type="ax25:RaterResponseAccessorial">
                    <ax25:aramount>12.66</ax25:aramount>
                    <ax25:accessorialid>22</ax25:accessorialid>
                    <ax25:accessorialname>Fuel</ax25:accessorialname>
                </ax25:accessorials>
                <ax25:ar_final_rate>161.66</ax25:ar_final_rate>
                <ax25:carrier_id>0000087</ax25:carrier_id>
                <ax25:carrier_name>CON-WAY FREIGHT INC</ax25:carrier_name>
                <ax25:service_days>04</ax25:service_days>
            </ax25:carriers>

            <ax25:message>Success</ax25:message>
            <ax25:referencenumber>3184877</ax25:referencenumber>
            <ax25:success>true</ax25:success>
        </ns:return>
    </ns:getrateresponse>
</soapenv:body>
```

Parse:

```
foreach($xml->ax25:carriers as $carrier) {
    $$carrierObject = array(
        "rate" => $carrier->ar_final_rate,
    );
    array_push($carriers, $$carrierObject);
  }
```

All I care about is the each `ax25:carriers` `ax25:ar_final_rate`. I also tried

```
$result = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
```

but get back

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (0) { }
```

Comment: Use [PHP's built in SOAP functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `DOMDocument` for extracting `textContent` inside these tags `<ax25:ar_final_rate>`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/795656)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='<soapenv:envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soapenv:body>
    <ns:getrateresponse xmlns:ns="http://services.gts">
        <ns:return xmlns:ax25="http://services.gts/xsd" xmlns:ax26="http://model.gts/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax25:RaterResponseAutoQuotes">

          <ax25:carriers xsi:type="ax25:RaterResponseCarriersAutoQuotes">
                <ax25:accessorials xsi:type="ax25:RaterResponseAccessorial">
                    <ax25:aramount>12.66</ax25:aramount>
                    <ax25:accessorialid>22</ax25:accessorialid>
                    <ax25:accessorialname>Fuel</ax25:accessorialname>
                </ax25:accessorials>
                <ax25:ar_final_rate>161.66</ax25:ar_final_rate>
                <ax25:carrier_id>0000087</ax25:carrier_id>
                <ax25:carrier_name>CON-WAY FREIGHT INC</ax25:carrier_name>
                <ax25:service_days>04</ax25:service_days>
            </ax25:carriers>

            <ax25:message>Success</ax25:message>
            <ax25:referencenumber>3184877</ax25:referencenumber>
            <ax25:success>true</ax25:success>
        </ns:return>
    </ns:getrateresponse>
</soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>';

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($string);
$carriers=array();
$results=$domDocument->getElementsByTagNameNS("http://services.gts/xsd", "ar_final_rate");
foreach($results as $result)
{
    array_push($carriers, $result->textContent);
}
print_r($carriers);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 161.66
)
```